# jQuery UI.Стоит ли переходить?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript, ui

Стоит ли использовать jQuery UI или только чистый jQuery?

Comment: Какой-то странный вопрос. Это библиотека на основе jQuery.
Тут личное дело каждого. пользоваться готовым или самому писать. Ничего плохого в jQueryUI я не вижу, по крайней мере пока... Только плюсы, многое из возможностей мне было кстати.

Comment: автор, вы хотя бы понимаете, что jQuery и jQuery UI - это две довольно разные вещи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery - это javascript фреймворк. jQuery UI - это набор готовых примочек(календарики, разные блоки,эффекты и т.п.) на jquery. jQuery UI и jQuery - это РАЗНЫЕ вещи. Делать примочки(которые есть в jQuery UI) самим или взять уже готовые решать Вам.

Answer (score 2):

Зачем jQuery? тем более jQuery UI ? Пишите на нативном "беспощадном" javascript - е. Потом поймете переходить или нет.

Comment: чем вас нативный js не устраивает?))

Comment: @nolka, против натива ничего не имею. А вот время не ждет увы, ну прекрасно понимаете же :)